# Change PDF file name in odoo v10

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have created a custom report in odoo v10, and here is my report action

```
<report
    id="my_custom_report_action"
    string="Sale Report"
    model="sale.order"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="module.custom_sale_report"
    file="module.custom_sale_report"/>
```

now when the report get printed I wanted to name a file like sale_SO001.pdf

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the pdf file(in Odoo V10) you can alter the report action using the record.

```
<record id="my_custom_report_action" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="print_report_name">'sale_%s.pdf' % object.name</field>
</record>
```

hope this helps!